# Private variable needs to be initialized only in constructor. How?

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, private

I have a class called `Foo` with a constructor that needs arguments, and a other class `Bar` with a `Foo` private variable

```
 class Foo 
 {
      public:
      Foo(string);
 }

 class Bar
 {
      public:
      Bar() { this->foo = Foo("test") }

      private:
      Foo foo;
 }
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get a compile error that there is no `Foo::Foo()` constructor. It looks like the private variable `foo` in class `Bar` gets initialized before getting a value assigned in the constructor.

How can I have a private `foo` variable that waits to gets initialized in my constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use an initializer list. If you don't, your code will call the default constructor for that object.

```
Bar::Bar() : foo("test") {
   // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use an initializer list:

```
Bar() : foo("test") {}
```

BTW, in C++ reasons to use `this->` are rare (and often indicate other problems).

Comment: Ok, yeah, I come from java,C# and just started trying some c++. Therefor my this-> usage. :)